# docker registry cant find files when ansible runs it

Tags: docker, ansible, docker-registry

I am trying to automate docker registry creating step using ansible. 
Here is my ansible-playbook :

```
---
- hosts: testansible
  tasks:

    - name: Getting docker registry
      become: true
      become_method: sudo
      become_user: root
      shell: docker run -d -p 443:443 --restart=always --name registry -v /home/myuser/certs:/certs -e REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR=0.0.0.0:443 -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/home/myuser/certs/domain.crt -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/home/myuser/certs/domain.key registry:2
```

When I run this, it doesnt give errors.

```
PLAY RECAP 
127.0.0.1                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

But in `docker logs`

> level=fatal msg="open /home/myuser/certs/domain.crt: no such file or directory"

But file is there in the exact location.

If I run `docker run` step manually, it creates docker registry without an error.
Why am I getting this error?

Here `testansible` is configured to use localhost.

Environment : Ubuntu 16.04

Ansible : ansible 2.8.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mounting `/home/myuser/certs` to `/certs` inside the container. You either need to update `REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE` and `REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY` to reflect this, or you need to change your volume mapping to `-v /home/myuser/certs:/home/myuser/certs`

Comment: When I do so, I get `tls: found a certificate rather than a key in the PEM for the private key`

Comment: I have to regenerate certificate files and it solved the problem. This was the issue.